# how to restrict checkboxlist selection up to 4 and on 5th selection it should clear only 5th selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

i need to create checkboxlist which should select max 4 items.
if user select the 5th item then it should clear particular 5th item only.
currently this code always clearing the first item of checkboxlist.

this is my c#:

```
 protected void lstSalesPerson_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var items = from ListItem li in lstSalesPerson.Items
                    where li.Selected == true
                    select li;

        Label1.Text = "";



        for (int i = 0; i < lstSalesPerson.Items.Count; i++)
        {

            if (lstSalesPerson.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                if (items.Count() > 4)
                {
                    Label1.Text = "checked maximum 4 items.";                      
                    lstSalesPerson.Items[i].Selected = false;
                }
            }
        }           
    }
```

this is my html:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstSalesPerson" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lstSalesPerson_SelectedIndexChanged">                                                    </asp:ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found answer using javascript it is as follows:
This might help someone: i'm using this control .multiselect-container > li > a > label > input because my control was rendered using this way in templates design. but you can use the logic for your code.. Thanks

```
  $('.multiselect-container > li > a > label > input').click(function (e) {              
            var ddl = document.getElementById("<%=lstSalesPerson.ClientID%>");               
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {                   
                var count = 0;                    
                for (var i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
                        if (ddl.options[i].selected) {
                            count++; 
                            if (count > 3) {                                   
                                $(this).removeAttr('checked');
                   $(this).parent().parent().parent().prop('checked', false);
                   $(this).parent().parent().parent().prop('clicked', false);
                   $(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass('active');
                                alert("You can select Max 4 sales person.");
                                return false;
                            } 
                        }
                }


            }
        });
```

Comment: this code is working correctly in chrome and other browser except IE.... Someone can help me or correct this code...that would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

you should reverse the loop as follows. In your loop it started from index[0] and check if total selected item is >4 if correct it will false the first item.

So the loop should be from the reverse index. so if 5 item selected then the first index selected will be [4] and it will get false

try below code

```
for (int i = lstSalesPerson.Items.Count-1; i >=0 ; i--)
{

            if (lstSalesPerson.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                if (items.Count() > 4)
                {
                    Label1.Text = "checked maximum 4 items.";                      
                    lstSalesPerson.Items[i].Selected = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks but now it is clearing last item...it should clear only last selected. what do i do?

Comment: @AjinkyaWavare didnt get you

Comment: previously it was clearing 1st item always when 5th item is getting selected...now it is clearing last element of the list item....it should clear the any middle i.e. 5th selected item only...

Comment: giving error on lstSalesPerson.SelectedItems.Count.....showing does not contain definition for selecteditems

Comment: @AjinkyaWavare you want to clear the last selected item?

Comment: yes means there are 8 items and if i select randomly 5 items then 5th one should be clear....